# What is the major product on mono chlorination of 2-methypentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

I understand that mono chlorination of 2-methylpentane are :
[image: Result of Mono Chlorination of 2-methylpentane]

My Question is : How can you determine the major product from those results ?

The probability of monochlorination of :

Amount of 1-chloro-2-methylpentane: 6 (number of 1°hydrogens) × 1.0 (relative reactivity) = 6.0

Amount of 1-chloro-4-methylpentane: 3 (number of 1°hydrogens) × 1.0 (relative reactivity) = 3.0

Amount of 2-chloro-4-methylpentane: 2 (number of 2°hydrogens) × 3.8 (relative reactivity) = 7.6

Amount of 3-chloro-2-methylpentane: 2 (number of 2°hydrogens) × 3.8 (relative reactivity) = 7.6

Amount of 2-chloro-2-methylpentane: 1 (number of 3°hydrogens) × 5.0 (relative reactivity) = 5.0

From the calculation above, the major product will be 2-chloro-4-methylpentane and 3-chloro-2-methylpentane with the same yield. But we should choose one from the two. I am confused. Do you have any idea ?